# Is FTP secure at the client end

Tags: security, ftp

If a client PHP application is periodically accessing a remote server via FTP, is there any security risks for the client?

I understand FTP is not inherently a secure protocol, but is this only the data over the connection is not secure?

Comment: If the client re-uses the password elsewhere, then using ftp means you have just handed out your password for something else that might need to be more secure.

Answer (score 1):

There are some possible attacks.

The first that comes to my mind would be a man-in-the-middle attack. This makes it possible to read and minpulate the data. It depends on what you do with the data. If you process it there might be a possibility for a security breach when the data is manipulated.

The easiest way to make it secure would be to add SSL/TLS ecryption to the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when using ftp software control connection is not encrypted so that username and password are passed as plaintext and could be intercepted. Same goes for data connection (directory listing and file transfers). If you need a secure solution make sure that your ftp server and ftp clients support SSL/TLS (FTPS).